# Input value not changing when i have preexisting value

Tags: reactjs, input, jsx, textarea, onchange

I have an ArticleFields component that loads an **article object** (through location.state) which has either **empty parameters**(when i try to make a new article) or **preexisting values** when i want to edit an article.My **inputs** though, **won't change** when i pass a preexisting value,even if it's an empty string.On the other hand ,the onChange function **still works for textarea**.Any ideas to why is this happening,i know i can just change the inputs to textareas,but ofcourse i want to understand why this is happening first

Here is a **sandbox for reference**

https://codesandbox.io/s/green-sound-sopdvp?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use defaultValue instead of value:

```
value={article.title}
```

Comment: Thanks you sir, too much vanilla  has messed my mind up